# what is the use of reduce command in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

tensorflow.**reduce**_sum(..) computes the sum of elements across dimensions of a tensor. it is Ok.

But one thing is not clear to me , what is the purpose of saying **reduce** in the function name ?

*Is it related to map_reduce of parallel computation?*
Let's say, it distributes the required computation to 
different cores , and collect the result from the cores , finally delivers the sum of the collected results ?

Answer (score 3):

Because you can compute the sum along a given dimension (and therefore reduce it). And no it has nothing to do with map-reduce.

Quoting the documentation string of the method:

> Reduces input_tensor along the dimensions given in axis. Unless `keepdims` is true, the rank of the tensor is reduced by 1 for each entry in axis. If `keepdims` is true, the reduced dimensions are retained with length 1.

Example from the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum):

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
tf.reduce_sum(x)  # 6
tf.reduce_sum(x, 0)  # [2, 2, 2]
tf.reduce_sum(x, 1)  # [3, 3]
tf.reduce_sum(x, 1, keepdims=True)  # [[3], [3]]
tf.reduce_sum(x, [0, 1])  # 6
```